# Does webpage content go to DRAM or Video RAM, and what if Video RAM runs out?

Tags: memory, browser, resources, html, video-memory

If the project has a page that uses jCarousel, and it has a `<ul>` (or `<div>`) that is 15860 x 375px, with 32-bit / pixel, that's close to 24MB.

Or, what if it is 1000 x 700 pixel per screenful, 6 screenful per webpage, and 5 tabs of such pages, with 32 bit per pixel

1000 x 700 x 6 x 5 x 4 = 84MB

does these 24MB or 84MB go to Video RAM or computer's DRAM?  If it is Video RAM, what if Video RAM runs out, does it swap to the computer's DRAM or hard drive?
(for example, a Virtual PC's Video RAM may be only 8MB or 16MB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data coming from the HTML rendering engine will normally be clipped to the visible portion of the window before being sent to the video memory.

Comment: so... it is residing in computer's DRAM, and only the visible part is sent to Video RAM?  So in that case, no more than the "screen resolution" portion of the whole screen is sent to the Video RAM, because at a time, the totality of "visible content" is the screen such as 1920 x 1200 itself.

Comment: @Jian: more or less, yes. I'm not sure all of it necessarily resides in main memory at any given time either. Just for example, I wouldn't be surprised if the rendering engine clipped a really huge `<div>` to some reasonable size before generating anything for it (but maybe not -- I've never really tried to figure out).